# Could not find agent library jdwp:transport on the library path

Tags: macos, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

How to run tomcat with debug from idea on mac, getting error:

```
/Users/konrad/Applications/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/bin/catalina.sh run
[2018-10-25 01:56:13,230] Artifact Gradle : com.test : MyService.war: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library jdwp:transport on the library path, with error: dlopen(libjdwp:transport.dylib, 1): image not found
Disconnected from server
```

**VM options**:
`-DprofileName=dev -agentlib:jdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000, suspend=n`

I'm using `InteliJ` and `Tomcat 9` with debug on Mac

Comment: The correct syntax to use is "jdwp=transport", not "jdwp:transport"

Comment: Thanks, works fine now

Comment: i would suggest you to look at --> [jwdp](https://virtual.osgiusers.org/2019/02/debug-jlink-java-image)